# Modulating audio signals in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, signals, signal-processing, communication

I have been trying to modulate and demodulate the default audio signal `speech_dft.mp3` in MATLAB using various modulation methods with no luck so far. Here is the code I have written up till this point

```
clear;
close;
clc;

%% Constants and Initialization
Ac = 1;                                         % Carrier Amplitude
Fc = 5.0e6;                                     % Carrier Frequency
Fs = 20e6;                                      % Sampling Frequency
Kf = 50;                                        % Frequency Deviation
Kp = 75;                                        % Phase Deviation
Beg = 1500;                                     % Sample to begin song from
SongStr = 'speech_dft.mp3';                     % Name of the File
Song = audioinfo(SongStr);                      % Getting Audio Info
L = 100;                                        % Length or number of samples
audio = audioread(SongStr);                     % Reading the Song
audio = audio(Beg:Beg+L-1,:);

%% Modulating

Wave(:,:,1)  = (ammod(audio,Fc,Fs));            % DSB-SC AM Modulation
Wave(:,:,3)  = (ammod(audio,Fc,Fs,0,Ac));       % DSB-FC AM Modulation
Wave(:,:,5)  = (ssbmod(audio,Fc,Fs));           % SSB-SC Lower Sideband AM Modulation
Wave(:,:,7)  = (ssbmod(audio,Fc,Fs,0,'upper')); % SSB-SC Upper Sideband AM Modulation
Wave(:,:,9)  = (fmmod(audio,Fc,Fs,Kf));         % FM Modulation
Wave(:,:,11) = (pmmod(audio,Fc,Fs,Kp));         % PM Modulation

%% Demodulating

Wave(:,:,2)  = (amdemod(audio,Fc,Fs));          % DSB-SC AM Demodulation
Wave(:,:,4)  = (amdemod(audio,Fc,Fs,0,Ac));     % DSB-FC AM Demodulation
Wave(:,:,6)  = (ssbdemod(audio,Fc,Fs));         % SSB-SC Lower Sideband AM Demodulation
Wave(:,:,8)  = (ssbdemod(audio,Fc,Fs));         % SSB-SC Upper Sideband AM Demodulation
Wave(:,:,10) = (fmdemod(audio,Fc,Fs,Kf));       % FM Demodulation
Wave(:,:,12) = (pmdemod(audio,Fc,Fs,Kp));       % PM Demodulation

%% Output

figure(1);
title('Demodulated')

subplot(3,2,1);
hold on;
plot(Wave(:,1,2));
plot(audio(:,1));
legend('DSB-SC','Original')
title('DSB-SC Demod');

subplot(3,2,2);
hold on;
plot(Wave(:,1,4));
plot(audio(:,1));
legend('DSB-FC','Original')
title('DSB-FC Demod');

subplot(3,2,3);
hold on;
plot(Wave(:,1,6));
plot(audio(:,1));
legend('SSB-Lower','Original')
title('SSB-Lower Demod');

subplot(3,2,4);
hold on;
plot(Wave(:,1,8));
plot(audio(:,1));
legend('SSB-Upper','Original')
title('SSB-Upper Demod');

subplot(3,2,5);
hold on;
plot(Wave(:,1,10));
plot(audio(:,1));
legend('FM','Original')
title('FM Demod');

subplot(3,2,6);
hold on;
plot(Wave(:,1,12));
plot(audio(:,1));
legend('PM','Original')
title('PM Demod');
```

I have kept the `Wave(:,1,2)` since I also tried working with audio files having two channels and plotting a single channel is much simpler.

This is the output that I get : [image: MATLAB Simulation Output]

As pretty much obvious from the image, the demodulated output is nowhere close to the original message signal but in some cases looks more like modulated signals. Can somebody tell where my mistake is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your code sample self contained and runnable ?  I do not know matlab yet looks like its not pulling in any libraries ... You will always get better help if your code is a :      Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: MATLAB does not require libraries. The code is completely self-contained and runnable.

Comment: FWIW, @Scott, you can add a link to the description of MCVE using the Stack Overflow specific shortcut `[MCVE]` , which gives you >> [MCVE] <<.

Comment: @Scott: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000